# variables not getting populated in sh of jenkins pipeline

Tags: shell, variables, jenkins, curl, jenkins-pipeline

I have the below code and username,pwd and modulename from previous stages are not getting populated when I'm doing curl in sh script.

Please let me know what do I need to fix it

```
def USERNAME
def PASSWORD
def MODULE_NAME
node {
    try {

        stage('userAuth') {
                    withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'ID-Creds',
                                  usernameVariable: 'user', passwordVariable: 'pwd']]) {
                        USERNAME="$user"
                        PASSWORD="$pwd"
                        echo "$USERNAME:$PASSWORD" //This is fine
                    }


        }

        stage('readPOM') {
            def pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'
            MODULE_NAME = pom.module
            echo "$MODULE_NAME"  //This is printing fine
        }

        stage('do curl') {
            def revision = sh(script: '''
                              AUTH="$USERNAME:$PASSWORD"; //Not getting populated getting empty
                              RespInfo=$(curl -u $AUTH  "https://host/apis/${MODULE_NAME}/deployments"); //Not getting populated getting empty for modulename
                              currntRev=$(jq -r .revision[0].name <<< "${RespInfo}"); 
                              echo $currntRev 
                              ''',returnStdout: true).split()
        }
    } 
    catch (e) {
        throw e
    } finally {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use double quotes (`"""`) to apply string interpolation:

```
def revision = sh(script: """
    AUTH=\"$USERNAME:$PASSWORD\"; //Not getting populated getting empty
```

Comment: now getting `illegal string body character after dollar sign;
   solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}" @ line 27, column 20.
            RespInfo=$(curl -u "${AUTH}" "https://host/apis/${MODULE_NAME}/deployments");`  .      Can I put the three lines in script?

Comment: I tried this `def revision = sh(script: """
        AUTH=\"${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD}\";
         RespInfo=\$(curl -u \"${AUTH}\"   \"https://host/apis/\"${MODULE_NAME}\"/deployments\");
         currntRev=\$(jq -r .revision[0].name <<< \"${RespInfo}\"); 
         echo $currntRev 
         """,returnStdout: true).split() `  . Now the error is `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: AUTH for class: groovy.lang.Binding`

Comment: You  are happily mixing up Groovy and Shell variables. `AUTH` is declared as a shell variable, and therefore you now have to escape the dollar sign so that Groovy doesn't interpret it: `curl -u \"\$AUTH\"`

Comment: Thanks for explanation. My first groovy script here. finally got it working with `def revision = sh(script: """ AUTH=\"${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD}\"; RespInfo=\$(curl -u \$AUTH \"https://host/apis/\"${MODULE_NAME}\"/deployments\"); currntRev=\$(jq -r .revision[0].name <<< \$RespInfo); echo \$currntRev """,returnStdout: true).split() `

Answer (score 2):

A easier way is to concat two strings as following:

```
def revision = sh(
  returnStdout: true,
  script: '''
    AUTH="$user:$pwd";
    RespInfo=$(curl -u "$AUTH"  "https://host/apis/''' + MODULE_NAME + '''/deployments");
    currntRev=$(jq -r .revision[0].name <<< "${RespInfo}"); 
    echo $currntRev 
  '''
).split()
```

**Note**:  string wrapped in `"""` will be expanded, but not when wrapped in `'''`

`USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` are Groovy variable, when they are wrapped in `"""` or `""`, Groovy executor will expand them before script be executed.

`user` and `pwd` are Shell variable, we should use Shell variable when use `'''`